# Independence between sigma fields

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

$\mathcal{F},\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2 $ are all $\sigma$ fields. If $\mathcal{F}$ is independent with $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ , is $\mathcal{F}$ independent with $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_1\cup \mathcal{F}_2)$?

Comment: Do you have a response to the answer below?

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand\F{\mathcal F}\newcommand\si{\sigma}$
No. Take any events $A_1,A_2,A$ that are [pairwise independent but not jointly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783225/example-of-pairwise-independent-but-not-jointly-independent-random-variables), so that
$$P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A)\ne P(A_1)P(A_2)P(A)=P(A_1\cap A_2)P(A). \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Let $\F_1:=\si(A_1)$, $\F_2:=\si(A_2)$, and $\F:=\si(A)$.

Then $\F$ is independent of $\F_1$ and of $\F_2$, but not of $\si(\F_1\cup\F_2)$ -- because $A_1\cap A_2\in\si(\F_1\cup\F_2)$ and in view of \eqref{1}.